# Python, WindowsError: [Error 32], file being used by another process

Tags: python-2.7

I'm writing a small programm that's supposed to loop through a folder of msg files (i.e. MS Outlook emails) and prefix a short string to their file names. I keep running into WindowsError: [Error 32] (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process) on line 33 (os.rename(filenameOLD, filenameNEW)). Any idea why?

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
import os

path = 'C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\SomeFile\\'
msgFiles = os.listdir(path) # returns list

count = 0
for msgFile in msgFiles:
    count = count + 1

    msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(path + msgFile)

    date = str(msg.SentOn)

    #Extract YYYY, MM, DD, HHMMSS from .msg sent date
    YYYY = str(20)+date.split("/")[2][:2]
    MM =  date.split("/")[1]
    DD =  date.split("/")[0]
    HHMMSS = "".join(date.split()[1].split(":")) + "Hrs"

    #Reformat date to valid file name    
    filenamePrefix =  YYYY + DD + MM + " " + HHMMSS + " "

    #generate new file name
    filenameOLD = path + msgFile
    filenameNEW = path + filenamePrefix + msgFile

    #rename file
    os.rename(filenameOLD, filenameNEW)

print count, "files renamed"
```

Comment: Is it possible that the file is still open from `outlook.OpenSharedItem`?

Comment: Might be. Not sure how to close it though

Comment: Do `del msg` after `date = str(msg.SentOn)`

Comment: Inserting  <code>del msg</code> just before <code>os.rename(filenameOLD, filenameNEW)</code> did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've opened the message without closing it. Instead do:

```
# ...
for msgFile in msgFiles:
    count = count + 1

    msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(path + msgFile)
    date = str(msg.SentOn)
    del msg
# ...
```